# unity how to load image from streamingassets on ios

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I put some png files into /Assets/StreamingAssets, what i want to do is load a image's texture from that floder.

here is my c# code below:

```
string path = "file://" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/sunny.png";

private IEnumerator GetMatByWWW(string url)
{
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;



    RawImage rawImage = gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>();
    rawImage.texture = www.texture;
}
```

On OSX, the code working perfect. But i need to make it working on IOS. So i remove the prefix of "file://" and the path is :

```
string path = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/sunny.png";
```

It just showed a red question-mark after build and run at my iPhone. And i also tried

```
string path = "file:/" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/sunny.png";
```

Who can tell me how to do it correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity Streaming Assets iOS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400634/unity-streaming-assets-ios-not-working)

Answer (score -2):

```
string ab_path = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + "bundlename";
AssetBundle ab = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(ab_path);

if(ab == null)
{
    Debug.Log("ab is null");
}

Gameobject prefab =  ab.LoadAsset<GameObject>("prefab_name");
Gameobject go = GameObject.Instantiate(prefab);
```

please check this link.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadFromFile.html

Comment: The OP isn't asking about asset bundle loading. Just a single file.