# Unity Streaming Assets iOS not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made an app in Unity which has been on the Google Play Store for over a year. Today I wanted to deployt it on Apple App Market but the translations don't work there.

I use the following code to load my app translations

```
public bool LoadLocalizedText(SystemLanguage language)
{
    localizedText = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "localizedText_" + language + ".json");

    WWW reader = new WWW(filePath);
    if (reader.text == null || reader.text == "") return false;
    while (!reader.isDone) { }
    string dataAsJson;
    dataAsJson = reader.text;
    LocalizationData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<LocalizationData>(dataAsJson);



     for (int i = 0; i < loadedData.items.Length; i++)
     {
         localizedText.Add(loadedData.items[i].key, loadedData.items[i].value);
     }


    Debug.Log("Data loaded, dictionary contains: " + localizedText.Count + " entries");
    if (localizedText.Count == 0) return false;
    else
    {
        isReady = true;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Yet somehow, all text fields display "Localized Text Not Found" because it cannot find my Assets... what could this be?

Is this because the StreamingAssets folder isn't copied to xCode?
Is it because the location is different on iOS?
Something else?

This is my folder structure
[image: Folder structure]

Comment: Does this work on Android? Can you show screenshot of where you put the json file?

Comment: @Programmer yes it does work on Android. I've included a screenshot now with the folder structure. inside StreamingAssets are the json files

Answer (score 5):

The `WWW` or `UnityWebRequest` API is used to read files on the StreamingAssets on Android. For iOS, The any API from the `System.IO` namespace such as `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` should be used.

Something like this:

```
IEnumerator ReadFromStreamingAssets()
{
    string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "MyFile");
    string result = "";
    if (filePath.Contains("://"))
    {
        UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest www = UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get(filePath);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        result = www.downloadHandler.text;
    }
    else
        result = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
}
```

---

Also, the `WWW` API is made to be used in a coroutine function so that you can wait or yield it until the download is complete. Your `while (!reader.isDone) { }` can freeze Unity. That should be  `while (!reader.isDone) yield return null;` which waits every frame until download is finished. The `LoadLocalizedText` function must also be a coroutine function so the return type should be `IEnumerator` instead of `bool`. To make it return `bool` too, use  `Action<bool>` as parameter.

After fixing both issues, below is what the new code should look like:

```
public IEnumerator LoadLocalizedText(SystemLanguage language, Action<bool> success)
{
    localizedText = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "localizedText_" + language + ".json");

    string dataAsJson;

    //Android
    if (filePath.Contains("://"))
    {

        WWW reader = new WWW(filePath);

        //Wait(Non blocking until download is done)
        while (!reader.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        if (reader.text == null || reader.text == "")
        {
            success(false);

            //Just like return false
            yield break;
        }

        dataAsJson = reader.text;
    }

    //iOS
    else
    {
        dataAsJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    }


    LocalizationData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<LocalizationData>(dataAsJson);



    for (int i = 0; i < loadedData.items.Length; i++)
    {
        localizedText.Add(loadedData.items[i].key, loadedData.items[i].value);
    }


    Debug.Log("Data loaded, dictionary contains: " + localizedText.Count + " entries");
    if (localizedText.Count == 0)
        success(false);
    else
    {
        isReady = true;
        success(true);
    }
}
```

And used like this:

```
StartCoroutine(LoadLocalizedText(languageInstance, (status) =>
{
    if (status)
    {
        //Success
    }
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! will sure give it a try and let you know if it helped. I will also change the if conditions to #if UNITY_ANDROID instead of detecting for myself what platform it is running on. I however must say that the file is not being downloaded but included in the binary so I don't really see a problem with my while condition without the yield return null

Comment: You don't have to add `UNITY_ANDROID` or check Android specifically. I already handled that with `if (filePath.Contains("://"))`.  Try the new `LoadLocalizedText` function in my answer and it if it works. Just copy it directly. As for `yield return null`, it doesn't matter if you are downloading or loading it. You should always yield very `WWW` operation. Again, this is to make sure that the code doesn't freeze Unity.

Comment: I meant replacing the if(filePath.Contains(...) with the Visual Studio checks. I get the error saying that not all code paths return a value

Comment: *"I meant replacing the if(filePath.Contains(...) with the Visual Studio checks."* Like I said above, you **don't** have to do that. The `if (filePath.Contains("://"))` in my code will do just that. This is because Android streamingasset path has "://" in it but not for other platforms. As for your error, that because you are missing `yield return null`. You need that. Maybe you don't see my code, refresh this post to see the Edit in  my code. The last code in my answer will just work if you copy it directly to your IDE. *Don't modify it.* Just copy it like lit is.

Comment: I just noticed another error in your code in which I used to create this answer. You were checking `if (reader.text == null || reader.text == "")` before the download is completed. That's not right. This should be done after the download has completed. I have updated the `LoadLocalizedText` function again. Just copy directly. Once you get it to work, you change it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

JsonUtility has a problem with iOS so it doesn't work
and if you test in local use File.OpenRead(path) works in iOS
filePath = Application.streamingAssetsPath

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(string.Format("{0}/{1}.txt", filePath, fileName)));
```

and streamingAssets read only if you want to write the file in iOS use this path -> Application.persistentDataPath

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is that Application.streamingAssetsPath is not fully correct for iOS device. You need to add **"file://"** manually to the path as well. Please note that it should be done outside of Path.Combine() method because for some reason, Combine() method strips it =) I wasted couple of hours trying to understand what is going wrong and I hope my post will save someone's time. Proper way to do is: **filePath = "file://" System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "MyFile");** The rest of the code is the same (this is true for AssetBundles as well)